# Owncloud community share: read/write permissions

Tags: owncloud

I can see on the demo site options for read/write on share files.

However my local server gives the following options:
[image: screenshot]

How to enable "can edit" "can share" ect...

Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was apparently a browser-side issue. No hint/log found from the community, I guess this is a rare case.

No fix found, closing.

Comment: Who will take the bounty do you know ? :D Will it just gone?